# Which Sanskrit dictionaries are people on this site using?

Tags: discussion, answers

Which Sanskrit-to-English online dictionaries do you use?

Do you find some work better than others? If so, why?

I use the following:

1. http://spokensanskrit.de/
   <sub>pros: fast lookup</sub>
   <sub>cons: not a detailed listing; doesn't explain etymology of words</sub>
2. Institute of Indology and Tamil Studies, Cologne University, Germany
    <sub>[sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/)</sub>

   - [Monier-Williams Sanskrit-English Dictionary](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/MW72Scan/2014/web/webtc/indexcaller.php)
   - [Apte Practical Sanskrit-English Dictionary, 1890](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/AP90Scan/2014/web/webtc/indexcaller.php)
     <sub>pros: examples of usage in Hindu scriptures is really good. I used this for my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16096/2995).</sub>
     <sub>cons: search could be tricky if you don't know [ITRANS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITRANS) or [Harvard-Kyoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard-Kyoto) well.</sub>
3. Archive.org

   - https://archive.org/details/1872sanskriten00moniuoft (Monier-Williams 1872)
   - https://archive.org/details/ldpd_7285627_000 (Vaman Shivaram Apte 1890)

And occasionally:

4. Digital South Asia Library (University of Chicago)
   <sub>[dsal.uchicago.edu/dictionaries/list.html](http://dsal.uchicago.edu/dictionaries/list.html#sanskrit)</sub>

   - http://dsal.uchicago.edu/dictionaries/apte/
     <sub>Apte, Vaman Shivaram. Revised and enlarged edition of Prin. V. S. Apte's The practical Sanskrit-English dictionary. Poona: Prasad Prakashan, 1957-1959. 3v.</sub>
   - http://dsal.uchicago.edu/dictionaries/macdonell/
     <sub>Macdonell, Arthur Anthony. A practical Sanskrit dictionary with transliteration, accentuation, and etymological analysis throughout. London: Oxford University Press, 1929.</sub>

Comment: I do use http://sanskritdictionary.com/

Comment: I don't use too often but when i do i use the 1st one

Answer (score 10):

There's a [विकिशब्दकोशः (Wiktionary)](https://sa.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%96%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A0%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D) compiled by many volunteers.

It features Apte, Kalpadrumam, Vachaspatyam, Monier Williams etc.

Comment: How I missed it!?

Answer (score 7):

I use [spokensanskrit.de](http://www.spokensanskrit.de/), [Andhrabharati Sanskrit Dictionary](http://www.andhrabharati.com/dictionary/sanskrit/index.php) and [Monier-Williams Sanskrit-English Dictionary](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/MW72Scan/2014/web/webtc/indexcaller.php).

I use spokensanskrit.de for faster look up and go for andhrabharati  if i don't get sastifactory meaning on spokensanskrit.de. I use Monier-Williams Dictionary to know meanings of [Dhatus](http://wiki.yoga-vidya.de/Sanskrit_Verbal_Roots_List_with_English_Translation) (verb roots).

I think we can't say which dictionary is better as it depends on situation and our requirement. For faster lookup, spokensanskrit.de is good and for Dhatus, Monier Williams is good.